# Mapping ranges of date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to map values defined in a dictionary of `date: value` into a DataFrame of dates.

Consider the following example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(range(19), index=pd.date_range(start="2010-01-01", end="2010-01-10", freq="12H"))

dct = {
    "2009-01-01": 1,
    "2010-01-05": 2,
    "2020-01-01": 3,
}
```

I would like to get something like this:

```py
df
                      0  test
2010-01-01 00:00:00   0   1.0
2010-01-01 12:00:00   1   1.0
2010-01-02 00:00:00   2   1.0
2010-01-02 12:00:00   3   1.0
2010-01-03 00:00:00   4   1.0
2010-01-03 12:00:00   5   1.0
2010-01-04 00:00:00   6   1.0
2010-01-04 12:00:00   7   1.0
2010-01-05 00:00:00   8   2.0
2010-01-05 12:00:00   9   2.0
2010-01-06 00:00:00  10   2.0
2010-01-06 12:00:00  11   2.0
2010-01-07 00:00:00  12   2.0
2010-01-07 12:00:00  13   2.0
2010-01-08 00:00:00  14   2.0
2010-01-08 12:00:00  15   2.0
2010-01-09 00:00:00  16   2.0
2010-01-09 12:00:00  17   2.0
2010-01-10 00:00:00  18   2.0
```

I have tried the following but I get a list of nan:

```py
df["test"] = pd.Series(df.index.map(dct), index=df.index).ffill()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are missing values, because no match types - in dict are keys like strings, in `DaatFrame` is `datetime`s in `DatetimeIndex`, need same types - here datetimes in helper `Series` created from dictionary with [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) for add datetimes between:

```
dct = {
    "2009-01-01": 1,
    "2010-01-05": 2,
    "2020-01-01": 3,
}


s = pd.Series(dct).rename(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)).asfreq('d', method='ffill')

df["test"] = df.index.to_series().dt.normalize().map(s)
print (df)
                      0  test
2010-01-01 00:00:00   0     1
2010-01-01 12:00:00   1     1
2010-01-02 00:00:00   2     1
2010-01-02 12:00:00   3     1
2010-01-03 00:00:00   4     1
2010-01-03 12:00:00   5     1
2010-01-04 00:00:00   6     1
2010-01-04 12:00:00   7     1
2010-01-05 00:00:00   8     2
2010-01-05 12:00:00   9     2
2010-01-06 00:00:00  10     2
2010-01-06 12:00:00  11     2
2010-01-07 00:00:00  12     2
2010-01-07 12:00:00  13     2
2010-01-08 00:00:00  14     2
2010-01-08 12:00:00  15     2
2010-01-09 00:00:00  16     2
2010-01-09 12:00:00  17     2
2010-01-10 00:00:00  18     2
```

Comment: Not sure about the different environment (pandas 1.3.3) but I get: `0  test
2010-01-01   0   NaN
2010-01-02   1   NaN
2010-01-03   2   NaN
2010-01-04   3   NaN
2010-01-05   4   NaN
2010-01-06   5   NaN
2010-01-07   6   NaN
2010-01-08   7   NaN
2010-01-09   8   NaN
2010-01-10   9   2.0
2010-01-11  10   2.0
2010-01-12  11   2.0
2010-01-13  12   2.0
2010-01-14  13   2.0
2010-01-15  14   2.0`

Comment: @yellowhat - I change `"2009-01-01"` to `"2010-01-01"` in dictionary, is it correct? Because no data `"2009-01-01"` in dataframe in question.

Comment: Ideally I would prefer to define `dct` arbitrarly, so to be sure I would pick a date out of the DataFrame range.

Comment: I have updated the question to consider the case of datetime (not only date).

Comment: @yellowhat - add [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html)